# Footnote - cite - Vgl. Jarchow/Rühmann (1988), S. 190

Tags: biblatex, citing, footnotes

I am writing my master thesis and I need this style of citation:

> Vgl. Jarchow/Rühmann (1988), S. 190.

This should be in footnotes.

I have done two variation of is. But it still not correct. The brackets are not on the place where they should be.

That is how is looks like:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,bibtotocnumbered,% Literaturverzeichnis ins Inhaltsverzeichnis
liststotoc,bibliography=totoc]{scrreprt}
%Chapter weiter oben beginnen
\renewcommand*\chapterheadstartvskip{\vspace*{-1.5cm}}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[left=2.50cm, right=2.50cm, top=2.50cm, bottom=2.50cm]{geometry}

%Deutsche Sprache
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{xcolor}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% %BILIOGRAPHIE  
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\usepackage[backend=bibtex, style=authoryear-icomp, sorting=nyvt, sortcase=false, maxnames=8, maxbibnames=8, minbibnames=8]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{MyCollection.bib} 
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{last-first} 
\DeclareNameAlias{default}{last-first} 
\renewcommand*{\multinamedelim}{\addsemicolon\addspace}




\begin{document} 

Hallo\footnote{\Parencite*[Vgl. Dai/Milkman/Katherine/Riis][S.12.]{Dai2013}}

Ja\footcite[Vgl.][12.]{Goulet2017a}
\newpage
\printbibliography[title={Literaturverzeichnis}]
\end{document}
```

I would be grateful if someone could help me. 
[image]

Comment: What version of `biblatex` are you using?

Comment: Excuse me where can I see which version I use?

Comment: You can find the version in the `.log` file. It is displayed more prominently (so you don't have to search for it) if you add `\listfiles` to the beginning of your document.

Answer (score 3):

The styles of my [`biblatex-ext`](https://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-ext) bundle make it easy to add a few parentheses that are not there in the standard styles.

Simply load `ext-authoryear-comp` instead of `authoryear-comp` and use `\DeclareDelimFormat`.

The MWE also uses `\autocite` as the go-to command and not `\footcite`.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,bibliography=totoc]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex, style=ext-authoryear-icomp,
  sorting=nyvt, sortcase=false,
  autocite=footnote,
  maxnames=8, minbibnames=8]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib} 

\DeclareInnerCiteDelims{footcite}{\bibopenparen}{\bibcloseparen}

\DeclareNameAlias{default}{family-given} 
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{default} 

\DeclareDelimFormat{multinamedelim}{\addsemicolon\space}

\begin{document} 
Lorem\autocite[Vgl.][12]{sigfridsson}

\printbibliography[title={Literaturverzeichnis}]
\end{document}
```

[image: Vgl. Sigfridsson und Ryde (1998), S. 12.]

You are still using BibTeX instead of the more powerful Biber backend. I suggest you switch to `backend=biber` and tell your editor to run Biber for you ([Biblatex with Biber: Configuring my editor to avoid undefined citations](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864)). You can only use the full set of `biblatex`'s features with Biber.